# Okhttp - Multipart - how to disable Content-Length for a part?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

Okhttp automatically adds `Content-Length` header for each part in request build with `MultipartBody.Builder`. I need to remove that header, because an API that I'm using does not allow it (and I can't do anything about it).

I've tried to add an interceptor to the request (both `addInterceptor` and `addNetworkInterceptor`) in order to remove that unwanted header. But it is not there (I can see only `Content-Disposition`). I've debugged their source code and it turns out that `Content-Length` is being added after the interception event.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? The only thing that comes to my mind is to build that request manually. I would have to write an interceptor that adds `multipart` header to the request and generates request body based on provided parts (with boundary, byte stream etc.).

**EDIT:**

Workaround:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2604

Comment: Any API that doesn't allow is is non-compliant with the HTTP specification.

Comment: I need to remove it as well for streams, where I can't know the content length.